# User input using c++ and Xcode terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, console

I have a simple c++ program that ask for user input using scanf.
When I run the program and try to type some input through the Xcode console, it sort of crashes.
It crashes when I try to make some user input.

It says "Lost Connection With ProjectName}
Like that:

```
int matriz[LIN][COL];
int l1, c1, l2, c2;

GENERATOR(matriz);

do{
    PRINT_ARRAY(matriz);

    printf("\nDigite a posição para realizar a troca");
    scanf("%d %d", &l1, &c1);
```

What is happening here?

I'm using Mac OSX Mavericks, and Xcode 5.

Comment: Show the code, not a screenshot of the error box.

Comment: Most likely you are calling `scanf` with non-pointer arguments, or a pointer-to-pointer string. But that's just a guess since it's impossible to tell without seeing the code. I suggest you read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you improve your questions.

Comment: I'm not using a non-address for scanf. Also, it works on terminal just fine.

Comment: And you're sure the problem is with `scanf` and not with `PRINT_ARRAY` or something else after the `scanf` call? Or something else completely? Have you tried running in a debugger?

Comment: It runs fine when using the terminal. Is it possible that i'm getting this error just because i'm using xCode terminal? I did use a debugger. It goes until the user input, and when I enter the input: crashes.

Comment: When it crashes, can you please show us the back-trace (the function call stack)?

Comment: Sure. Just a minute. It sort of terminates the debugger. Cause I can't find the stack trace. And i'm not sure it's scanf. I don't know if when I provide the input it's still scanf running. I think it is.

Comment: The likeliest explanation is that you have a bug in your code, which is causing your program to crash in certain circumstances. Can't really help with this kind of problem unless we can see a complete program.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that. But that means if I run a "safe-program" it should run, right? There's is the program: http://pastebin.com/RP5HE7Wr

Comment: So, do you guys have any clue of what is happening?

Comment: It does not crash for me in XCode. What input causes it to crash for you?

Comment: you must do the input through Xcode. And make any input. 1 0 for example

Comment: You have an infinite loop caused by this statement in `GENERATOR()`: `while(CHECK_ADJACENT(matriz, i, j))`.  This is because `CHECK_ADJACENT()` always returns non-zero as `enum CrashDirection` starts at 1.  Also `CHECK_ADJACENT()` accesses out-of-bound elements of the double array.

Comment: @PatrickBassut: It works perfectly when I input "1 0" in my XCode 5. Does putting a space before the first `%d` in each of your `scanf`s help in any way?

Comment: @trojafoe CHECK_ADJACENT has a return 0; down there. Also it's not a problem with the code cause it works perfectly on terminal.

Comment: It works when using the left enter(and not the enter on the numpad). That's the solution I got so far. But why that doesn't work with the numpad's enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the "lost connection with ProjectName" error, I used the left enter of my keyboard and not the one localized at the numpad.

Still trying to figure out why that happens.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem with c and objective-c terminal programs.
Based on things I found it is a bug in XCode.

Never mind information below:  You need to use RETURN Key on your keyboard and not an ENTER Key.

But I found the following 2 workarounds:

1. I was getting lost connection error, only when I used input from BT keyboard.  When I used native keyboard on my laptop, terminal accepted inputs.
2. In case if you have lid on your laptop closed then follow this workaround. Under Products locate your compiled file, right mouse click to locate it in Finder.  While in Finder, right mouse click to run in terminal.
   Your programs will run with no problems and terminal will accept your inputs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Running the program on bash works just fine. My problem really was on Xcode. As you mentioned, what are the things you're basing on?